# Is there a function that returns with a boolean value of a mouse hover? V5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I would like to plot something only for that certain candle which (or the vertical position of which) the mouse is pointed on.

For example:

```
plot(MouseIsHovering ? SuperDuperEMA : na)
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to check where the mouse hovers through Pine. The closest you can get to this is an interactive moveable input with `input.time(confirm=true)`:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")
bar = input.time(0, confirm=true)
sma = ta.sma(close, 100)
plot(time == bar ? sma : na)
```

Comment: Hm, interesting. And how to make it ask me again?

Comment: It only asks once, when you first add the script to the chart. But you can move the line after you placed it by dragging it on the chart by its anchor.